# index of JSON object with input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to get index of json object using input value?!

So actual when user input will be 2, My Javascript will print: 2nd question from JSON with id:2 and index 1  , and after that when he click next he will get 3rd question with id:3 and index 2 etc.

But because i need to add some questions to my course(many topics) i can't just changing id over and over or add questions after the last one.

So i need to search question using id... not index number. so if user input will be 2, my js schould print:  3rd question from JSON with id:2 and index 2  , and after that when he click next he will get 4rd question with id:9 and index 3 etc.

HTML - input value(user select id number):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Question Number" name="search" id="searchid" >
  <button type="submit" id="idnumber"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

So actual when user input will be 2, My Javascript will print: 3rd question from JSON, and after that when he click next he will get 4th question etc.

GetJson from file:

```
$.getJSON("question.json", function(response) {
      json = response;
      populate(json.Math[val]);

  });
```

Json:

```
{"Math":[
    {   "title":"Math",
        "subtitle": "some",
        "subtitle2" : "some2",
        "id": "1", 
        "question":"2+2:",
        "opt01": "5",
        "opt02": "22",
        "opt03": "4",
        "opt04": "3",
        "opt05": "1",
        "correct": "4"
         }, 
        { "title":"Math",
        "subtitle": "some",
        "subtitle2" : "some2",
        "id": "4", 
        "question":"2+12:",
        "opt01": "5",
        "opt02": "22",
        "opt03": "14",
        "opt04": "3",
        "opt05": "1",
        "correct": "14"
         },  { "title":"Math",
        "subtitle": "some",
        "subtitle2" : "some2",
        "id": "2", 
        "question":"21+2:",
        "opt01": "5",
        "opt02": "23",
        "opt03": "4",
        "opt04": "3",
        "opt05": "1",
        "correct": "23"
         },  { "title":"Math",
        "subtitle": "some",
        "subtitle2" : "some2",
        "id": "9", 
        "question":"2-2:",
        "opt01": "5",
        "opt02": "22",
        "opt03": "4",
        "opt04": "0",
        "opt05": "1",
        "correct": "0"
         },  { "title":"Math",
        "subtitle": "some",
        "subtitle2" : "some2",
        "id": "15", 
        "question":"(2+2)*10:",
        "opt01": "5",
        "opt02": "22",
        "opt03": "40",
        "opt04": "3",
        "opt05": "1",
        "correct": "40"
         }]}
```

Already try(jQuery):

```
   $("#idnumber").on('click', function(event) {
    inputvalue = $("#searchid").val();
      idinput = jQuery(json.Math[val]).index({"id": inputvalue });
            val = idinput;
          populate(json.Math[val]);
        });
```

For fast output i try "alert" , but every time i put some number my result is -1??

Comment: What does `$(json.Math[val]).index({"id": inputvalue });` do?

Comment: for now nothing :D i try to find index number for question with ID=(inputvalue) putted by user. inside my json file... but ye...

Comment: even if i put $(json.Math).index({"id": inputvalue }); still i have output like -1

Answer (score 0):

You can find an item in an array using `find()`. It takes a function, passes each item to the the function and will return the first object where the function returns `true`. So you if you want to find question id 2 you can:

```js
let qs = {"Math":[{   "title":"Math","subtitle": "some","subtitle2" : "some2","id": "1", "question":"2+2:","opt01": "5","opt02": "22","opt03": "4","opt04": "3","opt05": "1","correct": "4" }, { "title":"Math","subtitle": "some","subtitle2" : "some2","id": "4", "question":"2+12:","opt01": "5","opt02": "22","opt03": "14","opt04": "3","opt05": "1","correct": "14" },  { "title":"Math","subtitle": "some","subtitle2" : "some2","id": "2", "question":"21+2:","opt01": "5","opt02": "23","opt03": "4","opt04": "3","opt05": "1","correct": "23" },  { "title":"Math","subtitle": "some","subtitle2" : "some2","id": "9", "question":"2-2:","opt01": "5","opt02": "22","opt03": "4","opt04": "0","opt05": "1","correct": "0" },  { "title":"Math","subtitle": "some","subtitle2" : "some2","id": "15", "question":"(2+2)*10:","opt01": "5","opt02": "22","opt03": "40","opt04": "3","opt05": "1","correct": "40" }]}

function getQuesionID(id) {
    return qs.Math.find(q => q.id = id)
}
// question 2
console.log(getQuesionID(2))
```

That's simple enough, but you also have a problem that you want the next question which may or may not be No. 3, right? If there's no three you want 4 or 5 or whatever is next. Sooner or later you will find that you should use a better data structure for your questions. Since your questions are ordered by ID, and array sorted by ID makes more sense and will be more efficient.

You can sort your questions with:

```
qs.Math.sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id)
```

This will let you find the question with an ID greater than or equal to the user request. So asking for 3 will deliver 4:

```js
let qs = {"Math":[{   "title":"Math","subtitle": "some","subtitle2" : "some2","id": "1", "question":"2+2:","opt01": "5","opt02": "22","opt03": "4","opt04": "3","opt05": "1","correct": "4" }, { "title":"Math","subtitle": "some","subtitle2" : "some2","id": "4", "question":"2+12:","opt01": "5","opt02": "22","opt03": "14","opt04": "3","opt05": "1","correct": "14" },  { "title":"Math","subtitle": "some","subtitle2" : "some2","id": "2", "question":"21+2:","opt01": "5","opt02": "23","opt03": "4","opt04": "3","opt05": "1","correct": "23" },  { "title":"Math","subtitle": "some","subtitle2" : "some2","id": "9", "question":"2-2:","opt01": "5","opt02": "22","opt03": "4","opt04": "0","opt05": "1","correct": "0" },  { "title":"Math","subtitle": "some","subtitle2" : "some2","id": "15", "question":"(2+2)*10:","opt01": "5","opt02": "22","opt03": "40","opt04": "3","opt05": "1","correct": "40" }]}

function getQuesionID(id) {
    // get the next question greater than or equal to id
    // this works because Math is sorted
    return qs.Math.find(q => q.id >= id)
}
qs.Math.sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id)

console.log(getQuesionID(3))
```

Now you just need to keep track of which question you are on and ask for 1+that id.

Comment: thanks for answer but. i don't need your 2nd part of it :D because i have different topics and different subtopics. So when user choose for example quiestion  with id 44(index = 10), after next button will get question with id 22(index = 11) becouse they are in same subtopic or next after it. but... anyway.. i use your code.. but... i get object OBJECT  that is my output :D

Comment: function getQuesionID(id) {
    return json.Math.find(q => q.id = id)
}
alert(getQuesionID(2));

Comment: my json data is inside a file question.json.... with 12 000 lines of code :D  and decode using PHP  i cant just put that all inside my main file :D

Comment: @Piotr You get the object because we are returning the whole question object. You need to decide which part of the question you want to `alert()` for example `alert(getQuesionID(2).question)` or `alert(getQuesionID(2).title)`;

Comment: yes i have output:D try every number getQuesionID(2).question, getQuesionID(5).question,  but... every time my output is for 1st question in database...

Comment: Not sure what to tell you — the snippets above using your input work.